# CORS Issue in Golang while accessing API from go-swagger UI

Tags: go, cors, swagger, go-swagger

I have implemented go-swagger for my API documentation which is running on a different port on my localhost and my application is running on the port 8888. I have implemented cors https://github.com/rs/cors

my code for implementing cors is

```
var Router = func() *mux.Router{
    router := mux.NewRouter()
    var c = cors.New(cors.Options{
        AllowedOrigins: []string{"*"},
        AllowCredentials: true,
        AllowedMethods :[]string{"POST", "PUT","GET","DELETE","OPTIONS"},
        AllowedHeaders:   []string{"Accept", "Authorization", "Content-Type", "X-CSRF-Token"},
        MaxAge: 300,
        // Enable Debugging for testing, consider disabling in production
        Debug: true,
    })


    RegisterHandler := http.HandlerFunc(controllers.Register)
    router.Handle("/api/register",c.Handler(middleware.RequestValidator(RegisterHandler,reflect.TypeOf(dto.UserRequest{})))).Methods("POST")
    fmt.Println("var1 = ", reflect.TypeOf(router)) 
    return router
}
```

When hitting the request from Postman it seems the code is running fine

**Postman Response Header**

```
access-control-allow-credentials →true
access-control-allow-origin →*
content-length →123
content-type →application/json
date →Wed, 14 Oct 2020 04:02:37 GMT
vary →Origin
```

As I have enabled debug while implementing cors middleware log printed on my console is as follows

**Console log**

```
[cors] 2020/10/14 09:32:37 Handler: Actual request
[cors] 2020/10/14 09:32:37   Actual response added headers: map[Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:[true] Access-Control-Allow-Origin:[*] Vary:[Origin]]
```

**Issue**

When I accessing the same API from Swagger-UI in the browser I am getting cors issue that the "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" header is not set

```
Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8888/api/register' from origin 'http://localhost:45601' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
```

And there is no log printed on the console.

**It seems while accessing the API from Swagger UI, cors middleware code is not accessible.**

Here is the bowser network call detail of the response for swagger

**HTTP METHOD = OPTIONS**

General

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8888/api/register
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 405 Method Not Allowed
Remote Address: [::1]:8888
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Response Header

```
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 14 Oct 2020 04:25:23 GMT
```

Request Header

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en-IN;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Cache-Control: no-cache
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8888
Origin: http://localhost:45601
Pragma: no-cache
Referer: http://localhost:45601/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36
```

**Fetch**

General

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8888/api/register
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Request Header

```
Provisional headers are shown
accept: application/json
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:45601/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36
```

Thank you!

Comment: Full code can be access on Github https://github.com/abhimanyu1990/go-connect

Comment: Do you use an incognito window? So the browser didn't cache an old version of your site?

Comment: No I haven't used the incognito mode. As I have restarted swagger multiple time and each time it start on new port

Comment: Did you end up resolving the issue above? If so, can you please share insights into how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow `OPTIONS` method on the router.

https://github.com/abhimanyu1990/go-connect/blob/main/app/conf/router.configuration.go#L30

```
router.Handle("/api/register", c.Handler(middleware.RequestValidator(RegisterHandler, reflect.TypeOf(dto.UserRequest{})))).Methods("POST", "OPTIONS")
```

Comment: I have already tried this but it doesn't make any difference.

Comment: I think it solves 405 method not allowed issue. I tested this on my side, it works

Comment: Yes, cloned your repo & tested well locally

Answer (score 0):

This is annoying when I work to try to enable CORS and write header in Go.
Finally, I create a struct wrapping ResponseWriter to detect header is already written or not and it work fine.

```
package router

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

const (
    noWritten     = -1
    defaultStatus = http.StatusOK
)

type ResponseWriter struct {
    writer http.ResponseWriter
    size   int
    status int
}

func (w *ResponseWriter) Writer() http.ResponseWriter {
    return w.writer
}

func (w *ResponseWriter) WriteHeader(code int) {
    if code > 0 && w.status != code {
        if w.Written() {
            log.Printf("[WARNING] Headers were already written. Wanted to override status code %d with %d", w.status, code)
        }
        w.status = code
    }
}

func (w *ResponseWriter) WriteHeaderNow() {
    if !w.Written() {
        w.size = 0
        w.writer.WriteHeader(w.status)
    }
}

func (w *ResponseWriter) Write(data []byte) (n int, err error) {
    w.WriteHeaderNow()
    n, err = w.writer.Write(data)
    w.size += n
    return
}

func (w *ResponseWriter) Status() int {
    return w.status
}

func (w *ResponseWriter) Size() int {
    return w.size
}

func (w *ResponseWriter) Written() bool {
    return w.size != noWritten
}
```

And in the response:

```
func respondJSON(w *router.ResponseWriter, status int, payload interface{}) {
    res, err := json.Marshal(payload)
    if err != nil {
        respondError(w, internalErrorStatus.number, internalErrorStatus.description)
        return
    }

    go w.WriteHeader(status)
    header := w.Writer().Header()
    header.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*")
    header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    header.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE")
    header.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*")

    w.Write([]byte(res))
}
```